# What is the best way to "compile" HTML templates in production?

Tags: templates, typescript, angular, gulp, source-maps

i'm developing my first Angular2 app and i'm using this folders structure:

```
components
    component1
        home.component.ts
        home.component.html
        home.component.scss
```

I'm using Gulp to run tasks for building the app. The final folders structure will be this one:

```
scripts
    somefile1.js
    somefile2.js
    ...
styles
    mine.css
    vendor.css
index.html
favicon.ico
```

Can you tell me what is the best way to incorporate HTML templates within Javascript files?
Besides i would be able to easily debug code, so i would see the original folders structure in browser's inspection tools.
I'm currently using `gulp-sourcemaps` plugin and `sourceMap` option set to `true` for Typescript compiler to do the same for Styles and Scripts.

What node plugins could i use to reach this purpose for HTML templates?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37727411/1876949).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, anyway i created the "html:binging" task in my `gulpfile.js`: http://pastebin.com/4NXJCN73, but in the `dist` folder i cannot see any html code in the Javascript file. Do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [gulp-angular-embed-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-embed-templates) on multiple projects with great success.

Here is an example task:

```
gulp.task('embed-templates', () => {
    gulp.src('app/**/**.js')
        .pipe(embedTemplates({sourceType:'js', minimize: {quotes: true, empty: true}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
```

Comment: Is possible to embed SASS files?

Comment: Not directly. You need to compile them provide the styleUrl in the component and then run this task. A good gulp library for this is: gulp-sass. But i haven't really tried embedding styles yet.

Comment: What about this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular2-embed-sass (sorry for OT)